# indent-buffer At top level

Tags: indentation

Not really sure why this has stopped working

When I run the command

```
indent-buffer
```

..it just says

```
At top level
```

Same if I mark the whole buffer and run indent-region.

Any way to debug this?;)

Comment: What's in your `*Messages*` buffer?

Comment: it says "user-error: At top level"

Answer (score 0):

Without further context, I assume you're trying to indent something "lispy", as you can find this exact error in `up-list` from [Emacs's `lisp.el`](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/0330cff65ae837e93ae4d059acf643734d16386d/lisp/emacs-lisp/lisp.el#L281). My quick read of it is that something has confused `up-list`, ie. you have a syntax error, or something valid but significantly "weird". By default `user-error` doesn't fire the debugger (see `C-h f user-error` for details) but I don't think it would be much help here anyway. Bisect your code (logically) and indent each half as you go. You should narrow down the trouble spot fairly quickly.